# angularjs how to describe module correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, controller

Why did i can't add the new item?? 
when I added in module [] - it doesn't work.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.controller('addItemCtrl',
['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.items = [];

$scope.additem = function() {
    $scope.items.push({'title': $scope.newItem, 'done':false})
    $scope.newItem = '';
}

$scope.deleteitem = function(index) {   
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
} }])
```

Comment: did you call the functions?

Comment: Yes, i did. 
<form name="itemsFrm" ng-submit="addItem()" class="input_items_form">
      <input name="newItem" ng-model="newItem" required class="form-control form">
      <button ng-disabled="itemsFrm.$invalid" ng-click="addItem()" class="btn btn-success add_btn">Add new</button>
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item.title}}
      </div>
    </form>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="{'fadeOut' : skill.done}">>
     {{item.title}}
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the UI part where you execute these functions?

Eg: https://plnkr.co/edit/7dA2IhINdgTe90ftyMt9?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="addItemCtrl">
    <p>Count {{items.length}}</p>
    <button ng-click="additem()">Add Item</button>
    <button ng-click="deleteitem()">Delete Item</button>
  </body>

</html>
```